# Attach SQL Database referencing new data file

Tags: sql-server, ssms, localdb

My issue is that I have a SQL database that is the output of a SQL project in an ASP.NET solution. This output consists of 2 datafiles, lets call them MainDB.mdf and DocContent.mdf, and the necessary log files. DocContent.mdf has one table, doc_content, which, you guessed it, stores the bytes for documents. There are multiple dev's working on this project, and we each have a (localdb) instance of the DB to use.

What I need to make happen is to attach *MY* MainDB.mdf referring to dev B's DocContent.mdf. The data FK's match 1:1, the schema is identical, the only difference is that Dev B populated the varbinary field with uploaded documents.

SQL seems to be doing everything in its power to prevent this. I get:
[image: SQL Error]

I realize I could do a Data Compare and pump the data in that way, but unfortunately Dev B and I are not at the same location and the logistics of him sending his full DB output would be harder than finding a work around with what I've got (I hope, anyway).

Surely there is a way to tell SQL to shut up and just use the datafile provided?

The only info I could find on this subject referred to attaching a DB without its LDF. Anyone know how to make this scenario work?

Comment: Other than the one in my post? Ummm, no

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/120625/one-or-more-files-do-not-match-the-primary-file-of-the-database-error-5173

Comment: Thanks, but this is neither the same problem nor the solution to mine. I had a look at that before I asked the Q.

Answer (score 0):

So, for anyone interested, the short answer is 'no'. There are a number of convoluted steps that you you can take to force the database into SUSPECT mode and possible even get it into single user emergency mode, but it was not worth the effort and the end result is that you will have to hack into the sys tables in order to make it limp along this way.

In the end it was easier to get a full transfer of Dev B's data files.